# Can someone help me identify which type of distribution this is and how to solve it?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Ok so I have this problem in which there is a certain distribution but I'm not sure I solved it right. Here's what it says:

The daily profit of a company is determined through random continuous variable in which E(x) = 30 and Var(X) = 450. Find, through an approximation, the probability of a monthly profit (30 days), which is superior to a million dollars.

So here's what I did:

First this looked like a normal distribution to me, second, since we're talking in terms of thousands, I thought they were asking for P(X < 1000). Finally I believe it was necessary to standardize this in order to get the approximate. Nonetheless, I believe something is off, and its those 30 days they mentioned. I'm not sure what to do with that. Which is why I'm not sure if the way I solved this is correct. Can someone help me out?

EDIT: Alright I think I have it, thank's to A.S. I realized this was a Central Limit Theorem problem so this is what I did:

$E(X) = 50$
$Var(X) = 450 $

$S_{30} \sim N(30\mu,30\sigma^2) = N(900,13500)$

$P(S_{30} > 1000) = 1 - \phi(\frac{1000 - 900}{\sqrt{13500}})$

Answer = 0.194

Don't know if everything is done properly, I would prefer if someone checked it. I'll leave it here, in case someone else runs into a similar problem.

Comment: Consider average per day earning - for any reasonable distribution of daily profits. Per CLT it's distributed close to $N(30,15)$ ($15$ is variance) and you need to find $P(N(30,15)>\frac {100}3)=P(N(0,1)>\frac {10}{3\sqrt{15}})$.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion between thousands and millions. Your $\phi()$ should probably be written as $\Phi()$. And my rounding would give about $0.195$.  Otherwise this looks correct

Comment: I see, I will check that out then. Thanks.